# Best specs for Sound bites (Media Release)

Tags: download, recordings, media

We are preparing a bunch of short sound bites to accompany a media release.

Wondering what specs are recommended for the audio recordings submitted to news/media outlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These will possibly differ between outlets, but in the absence of any documented specs, I would do the following:

1. File format BWAV PCM 16 Bit Stereo
2. Loudness Target -24LUFS
3. Loudness Range <12LU

At least this gives you a consistent starting point.